# com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Locator.getVersion() - What is this method used for?

Tags: gwt

I'm writing my first `GWT-Application` and need your advice. I have no problems implementing a locator for database entities where I can reuse the version-column used for optimistic locking by hibernate, but one of my entities represents a `ldap-Object`. Can you tell me what the method `getVersion()` of the Locator is used for and how I can implement this method for my `ldap-Object?` I will do read and write ldap objects.

Answer (score 2):

From [GWT documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory?hl=pl), `getVersion` method is

> Used by RequestFactory to infer if an entity has changed. The backing store (JDO, JPA, etc.) is responsible for updating the version each time the object is persisted, and RequestFactory calls getVersion() to learn of changes. This information is used in two places. First, the RequestFactoryServlet sends an UPDATE event to the client if an entity changes as a result of the method invocation on the server, for example, when a call to persist an editable entity results in an updated version on the server. Second, the client maintains a version cache of recently seen entities. Whenever it sees an entity whose version has changed, it fires UPDATE events on the event bus so that listeners can update the view.
>
> Since many persistence frameworks offer generic find/get/query methods, it's also possible to create a generic Locator class and specify it in the @ProxyFor annotation for each entity type. To do this, all your entities can extend a base class that provides getId() and getVersion(). Alternatively, the generic Locator can use reflection to call getId() and getVersion() when needed.

Not sure if you're looking for anything else in addition to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My first thought was to use the Attribute modifyTimestamp and createTimestamp. But there is still a functional gap:
The smallest unit of These timestamps is seconds so a Change in the same second can not be detected. Another solution would be to use a kind of checksum over all attributes of the ldap object. Not very nice..